# How can a Netty Server porcess a client request using another Netty Client for Http2 Proxy Server

Tags: networking, netty, http2, http-proxy

My requirement is if a browser sends the request to ServerBootStrap then the ServerBootStrap creates BootStrap (Client) and that client connects with a proxy server.

The problem here is to connect with Proxy Server we need to send first HTTP CONNECT method to open a tunnel from Proxy and BootStrap (Client) and then whatever request comes from Browser to Server, the server will send BootStrap(client) and all the communication should happen.

This will look like

Browser ->ServerBootStrap(Server)->BootStrap(Client)->ProxyServer(HTTP2)

1. Can somebody tell me how do I implement this for Http2?
2. How do I send Http CONNECT from a Handler for the First time while Client instantiating and If CONNECT gets 200OK from Proxy Server I will to remove Handler from channel pipeline?
3. Can we explicitly call any HTTP CONNECT request while adding a handler in Pipeline and getting the response to check the status?

--Can somebody answer ?